# Continue a formula while skipping cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I need a formula to continue in every 6 cells.

Example:

- Formula `=grades!A1` in cell B1
- Formula `=grades!A2` in cell B8
- Formula `=grades!A3` in cell B15

… and so on, all the way down my column without having to do it manually. Basically skipping 6 cells then entering formula.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this **does not work** if there is something in the skipped rows!

For example

```
B1
asd
...
pof
rty
B8
```

---

Use this formula on your B column

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(), 7)=1, INDIRECT("grades!A"&CEILING(ROW()/7, 1)), "")
```

Basically if current row is 1, 8, 15, ... it will get the value from sheet `grades`, if not then it is empty.

You can use this on `B1` then drag it down.

**Or**

You can leave the skipped columns empty by putting formula above **or** Scott's formula below on `B1` and `B8`, then selecting **through `B1` until `B14`**, then proceed to drag it down.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(), 7)=1, INDIRECT("grades!A"&(ROW()-1/7)+1), "")
```

Comment: Good answer. I would have written the ``INDIRECT`` string as ``"grades!A" & (ROW()-1)/7+1``, but that’s basically a matter of personal preference and what seems more intuitive to you.  Mine is slightly shorter; arguably, yours may be more robust.

Comment: I think actually yours is better. Using function slow down the calculation, and if it can be achieved by math, then it is better. I haven't checked it yet, but what happened if the `(ROW()-1)/7+1` does not return an integer? And I hope you don't mind if I add this into my answer.

Comment: (1) You’ll get something like `INDIRECT("grades!A1.142857")`, which will throw a `#REF` error.  I guess that’s another advantage of your approach — but, once you’ve got the formula right, it’s right; you don’t have to worry about an error like that cropping up some time in the future.  (2) Go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

You will need the assistance of a helper column for this method.

In cell B1, enter this formula `=Grades!A1`

In cell B8, enter this formula `=INDIRECT("Grades!A"&RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(($B$1)),1) + CEILING(ROW()/8,1))`

Now the helper column: Fill Column D with this formula `=MOD(ROW(),7)`

Apply a filter to all the data. Filter column D showing only 1 values.  This should display every 7th row (i.e. six blank rows between values).  This allows adding the formula if the 6 cells between are not empty.

Copy the formula in cell B8 and paste it into the visible rows in column B.

Un-filter the data and delete the formulas in column D.

Comment: (1) You misread the question, so you are displaying values in cells `B1`, `B8`, **`B16`**, **`B24`**, …, rather than  `B1`, `B8`, `B15`, `B22`, …, as requested.  (2) While using a helper column to hide the majority of the rows, allowing the user to enter something into a selected subset of the rows, is a cute trick, there’s a much easier way — see [Vylix’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1222980/150988#1222997).  (3) `RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(($B$1)),1)` evaluates to a constant: 1. Why do it the hard way? If you have a reason, [edit] your answer to explain it. Please do not respond in comments.